# Scala match subclass with parameter

Tags: scala

I have a parent abstract class `P`:

```
abstract class P {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
}
```

Then I have 2 subclasses `Empty` and `NonEmpty`:

```
class Empty extends P {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
}
```

In `NonEmpty`, I need to define a function `union` as follows:

```
class NonEmpty(name: String) extends P {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  def union(that: P): Unit = {
    that match {
      case e: Empty => print("empty")
      case n: NonEmpty => print("NonEmpty:" + n.name)
    }
  }
}
```

However, I got an error as:

```
14: error: value name is not a member of NonEmpty
     case n: NonEmpty => println("NonEmpty:" + n.name)
                                                 ^
```

How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply make `name` a public (i.e. visible) value member of the class.

```
class NonEmpty(val name: String) extends P { ...
```

Or you could turn it into a `case class`.  With that the parameter is made public automatically and the pattern matching a little more clean and concise.

```
case NonEmpty(n) => print("NonEmpty:" + n)
```

Comment: `typeOf[NonEmpty].member(TermName("name")).isPrivateThis` is true, so it's already a value member as mentioned on the other answer. The captured field is not just an artifact.

Comment: Ack! Terminology trips me up _again_.

Comment: Also, its memberness doesn't in any way depend on "a field was emitted in byte code." I was just tired & confused.

Answer (score 2):

`name` is the argument for the constructor of the class but the field hasn't been assigned that value for the objects of `NonEmpty` class.

Replace
`class NonEmpty(name: String) extends P`
with
`class NonEmpty(val name: String) extends P`

Doing this defines a field and assigns the value passed in the constructor.

It seems that you are using these classes to model a tree like data structure. In that case, it would make sense to define `Empty` as an object instead of a class.

Comment: The field does exist, it's just private.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov `private[this]`. I had to check that you can actually look it up, and yes you can. Thx.